# How would I extract a single byte from an int array at a given byte index?

Tags: java, c, arrays, int, byte

Given an array of ints `A`, write C or Java code that will extract a single byte from the array at (byte) index `n` and assign it to an int variable `b`.

This is part of a class assignment. I am not even sure how to start this. Would I need to somehow convert the whole int array into a byte array, grab it out, then convert it back to an int? Or should I think about each integer in the array being 4 bytes. I would divide my byte index by 4 to find out which integer it is in and then work something from there?

Im not looking for the answer, just some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to first locate the correct int, then use bitshift to align the desired byte properly, and finally mask the integer with binary and (`&`).

Note that unlike Java, C doesn't specify the size of `int` to be exactly four bytes so a pedantic C solution would require your program to take into account larger than 4-byte integers.

I hope this is the kind of guidance you wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question correctly, firstly you can make use of bitwise shift operator `>>` to get single byte from `nth` index array element as,

```
 int single_element_byte = (number >> (i * 8)) & 0xff; 
 /* Where (0 <= i <= 3) - 0: First byte; 1: Second byte */
```

Secondly, you can traverse array `A` every `nth` index to compute above single byte. Note the contents of variables can be big/little endian, if those are modified then you aren't guaranteed for correct values.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, the user give you the position of the byte to extract and index of the int in the array A ?

if i did, then you should get the int value at the given index from the array
then you should convert the int value to byte array (byte[]) and then get the value at byte[n]
and convert the value of it back to int and store in "b"

Answer (score -1):

Well, since you tagged it as C. I'm going to exploit casting in C.

Note that one char is one byte.

So we can cast the int array to a char*.

Then access the char* as an array at any given byte index.

The valid indexes, would range from 0 to sizeof( int ) * (int array length).

Oh, and because you need the answer in an int. Just say int answer = byteArray[index]

a char is an just an int that has a max value of 2^4